# how to change text dynamically added button c#

Tags: c#, button

Add Buttons:

```
Button button = new Button();
this.Controls.Add(button);
button.Name = "btn" + id;
button.Text = "AAAA";
```

The result is the name of a button as `btn55`, but, how to change text on button name `btn55`?

something like

```
private void btnaktual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    btn55.Text = "BBB";                  
}
```

Gives me error:

> Error  1   The name 'btn55' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It should be `button.Text = "BBB"` in the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.Controls.Find("btn55",true).FirstOrDefault().Text = "BBB";`

Answer (score 1):

If you used the designer to put the button in the form, then a member variable would be created with the same name as the name of the form. As you create the button using code, there is no `btn55` variable.

When you create the button you have a reference to it. You should just keep that reference so that you can use it later. Make a member variable in the form where you can store it, i.e. declare `Button button;` (or perhaps a more descriptive name) in the form class instead of inside the method where you create the button. Then you can use the variable later to access the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var btn = Controls.Find("btn55") as Button;
btn.Text = BBB;
```

Comment: `Controls.Find` returns `Controls[]` so you can't cast it to `Button`. See *Rariolu*'s answer

Comment: You need to explain your code: what's wrong with the OP's code, why this solves the problem, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire problem lies in the page load. When you click the button event the page posts back, so if you're control is not reloaded it no longer exists when the click event is called. Either you are not creating the button on postback or the button isn't in viewstate. Find Control will always return null until the button is created so most of these answers won't work for you yet.

These pages will help you:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1186195.aspx?FAQ+Why+do+dynamic+controls+disappear+on+postback+and+not+raise+events+

[Dynamically Created Controls losing data after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35360/ViewState-in-Dynamic-Control

Once you get that control reloaded, then you can get it from there pretty easily.

Comment: So you are sure it is not a winforms application.

Comment: well it would help if he specified, I assumed it was .net. If it's not he can ignore it and will help someone else maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You need to search for the button in it's parent controller. Let's say you have a main form and the button placed in it. You can find using id of control in parent.
`(MainForm.Controls.Find("btn"+number") as Button).Text= "BBB";`