# retrieve the label.text from placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I add a label with its respective text to show dinamically using placeholder in ASP.NET coding C#, the next snippet is to show what I have for the time being

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label label1= new Label();
            label1.ID="lbdin";
            label1.Text="agregado dinamicamente";
            TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
            textbox1.Text = "textbox dinamico";
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "btn";
            btn.Text = "boton dinamico";
            btn.Click += DynamicButton;
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(label1);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(textbox1);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
```

the controls appears dinamically in the placeholder, that works fine, my problem comes out when I try to retrive the text that the label control shows, in order to do that I've added a button and coded the next

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label Referencia_lb = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("lbdin") as Label;

    //Label Referencia_lb = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("lbdin") as Label;
    Referencia_lb.Text = "CAMBIANDO EL TEXTO DEL OBJETO CREADO EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCION";
}
```

but when debug the application I got the error

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebApplication2.dll but was not handled in user code

could you please help me and tell me how to retrieve the text from the label that is created automatically into the placeholder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback seems like a very similar issue here.

Comment: @JBKing hello, yes, just checked the link and now I can retrieve the text property from the label just by paste my code in the Load event, but if I do that the page seeems like it is loading a normal page with its controls and what I need is that when the user click a button the placeholder add and shows automatically the controls, any idea?

Comment: I'd be careful about what kind of state are you expecting the page to be at various times here that could likely be the issue. There are likely more than a few solutions but I seem to remember having to recreate dynamic controls in my past a few times when I had this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the PlaceHolder1.FindControl("lbdin") as Label with:

```
var lbdin = PlaceHolder1.Children.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == "lbdin") as Label;
```

then you need to test for null.

```
if(lbdin != null) 
{
    lbdin.Text = "Your Text";
}
else
{ Response.Write("alert('could not find label');"); }
```