# Dynamic gridview always become empty when i have postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a `Gridview` which is being created dynamically based on text input.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSession" runat="server" ShowFooter="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer hover gvv" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
      <Columns>
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

So, whenever my page have a `PostBack`, the `controls` such as `TextBox` and `Label` that is being created dynamically in the `Gridview` always disappear, thus the `Gridview` will be left with the number of rows created previously but is empty.

Is there a way to 'save' the information of the `Gridview`? Or am I just doing wrongly for my creation of `Gridview`

Here's how I created my `Gridview`.

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void tbClassSession_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GenerateRows();
        }

        private void SetInitialRow()
        {
            int numbers = int.Parse(this.tbClassSession.Text.Trim());
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //you can add as many rows you want 
            dt.Columns.Add("Session No.", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Lesson Date", typeof(DateTime));
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add("", null);
            }
            gvSession.DataSource = dt;
            gvSession.DataBind();

        }

        protected void GenerateRows()
        {
            this.SetInitialRow();
            int numbers = int.Parse(this.tbClassSession.Text.Trim());

                int cellCount = this.gvSession.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                int rowsCount = this.gvSession.Rows.Count;
                foreach (GridViewRow row in this.gvSession.Rows)
                {
                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.Text = (row.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
                    label.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
                    row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(label);
                }

                int rowCount = 0;

                foreach (GridViewRow row in this.gvSession.Rows)
                {
                    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
                    textBox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Date;

                    textBox.Text = "Hello World"
                }

        }
```

Comment: can you please add `gvSession.DataBind();` in last line of method `GenerateRows()` and let me know what happens ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Created Controls losing data after postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback)

Comment: @AnkitkumarBhatt The `gvSession` is empty when i input into the `textbox` which triggers the creation of `Gridview`

Comment: Here I can see you are calling `SetInitialRow()` in `GenerateRows()` so it will have something so you can add `gvSession.DataBind();` in the last line of `GenerateRows()`.