# Dynamically generated checkbox always has Checked==False on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I have a `asp:panel` that on a button click, I add some number of checkboxes to dynamically.

On another button click, I need to look at these checkboxes and check if they are checked.

This is a follow up question to one I posted earlier. The first issue was I could not find the dynamically generated controls at all on postback.

Now, I can find them. The problem is the `Checked` property is always false despite checking the checkbox on the UI.

The markup with the panel that the checkboxes get placed into, and the two buttons:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" ID="pnlEmailCheckboxes" Height="150">
    <br/>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="Other" ID="cbOtherEmail"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherEmail" runat="server" Style="width: 270px;" CssClass="textbox-default"></asp:TextBox>
    <br/>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendEmail" Text="<span>Send Email</span>" runat="server" CssClass="page-footer-button-highlight" OnClick="btnSendEmail_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCloseEmail" Text="<span>Close</span>" runat="server" CssClass="page-footer-button" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnCloseEmail_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>
```

The event that generates the textboxes:

```
protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CheckBox> cbList = new List<CheckBox>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Text = "text" + i;
        cb.ID = Guid.newGuid().ToString();
        cb.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        pnlEmailCheckboxes.Controls.AddAt(0, cb);
        pnlEmailCheckboxes.Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        cbList.Add(cb);
    }

    Session["checkboxes"] = cbList;
    mpeEmail.Show();
}
```

The button that tries to retrieve the textboxes (does not work):

```
protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //the email recipients
    List<string> emailRecipients = new List<string>();

    List<CheckBox> cbList = (List<CheckBox>)Session["checkboxes"];

    foreach (CheckBox cb in cbList)
    {
        CheckBox cbClient = (CheckBox) pnlEmailCheckboxes.FindControl(cb.ClientID); //I've also tried to find it by cb.ID
        //ALWAYS FALSE
        if (cbClient.Checked) emailRecipients.Add(cb.Text.Trim());
    }

    //Ive also tried this, it does not contain the dynamically generated checkboxes
    //var cbControls = pnlEmailCheckboxes.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
}
```

Edit:

The client side html even shows the  with the correct ID that matches the ID I'm searching for.

```
<input id="00e3a485-2083-4ef8-810b-6ed4fb1f62f9" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$Body$00e3a485-2083-4ef8-810b-6ed4fb1f62f9">
```

Comment: I prefer to use a Repeater of checkboxes instead of adding them dynamically. In your case you have to create checkboxes again after postback (OnLoad). Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback

Comment: @Emanuele I am indeed creating the controls on the postback, however that link lead me to the realization that the controls being re-created need to have the same IDs as the old controls to be mapped to the re-created controls. thanks.

Comment: Nice. Can i suggest to use a "more controlled" naming convention for checkboxes? EG chk1, chk2...

Comment: @Emanuele Sure but those names are purely for this stack-overflow question in the interest of a MCVE "minimum complete verifiable example"    or whatever the acronym is. My actual code is different.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls need to be re-created on each postback (which was already happening, given I was creating them in the page `OnInit` function).

However, the problem is that I was using a newly genered Guid as the ID for each control. This was causing the re-generated controls on each postback to not be mapped to the postdata from the old controls.

```
protected void btnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<CheckBox> cbList = new List<CheckBox>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Text = "text" + i;

        //cb.ID = Guid.newGuid().ToString(); //don't do this.
        cb.ID = "checkbox" + i; // <------ do this, have a consistent ID

        cb.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        pnlEmailCheckboxes.Controls.AddAt(0, cb);
        pnlEmailCheckboxes.Controls.AddAt(0, new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        cbList.Add(cb);
    }

    Session["checkboxes"] = cbList;
    mpeEmail.Show();
}
```