# Unable to find dynamically generated control in placeholder in ASP.NET Webforms app

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a placeholder on my ASPX Page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="phControlContainer" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In the code behind on PageLoad I generate a RadHtmlChart with an ID="MyChart" and add it to the placeholder by doing the following:

```
phControlContainer.Controls.Add(chart);
```

I can see it on the page at this point.

Then on another PostBack OnButtonClick I want to modify the chart so I attempt to find it:

```
RadHtmlChart chart = (RadHtmlChart)phControlContainer.FindControl("MyChart");
```

It finds nothing and chart is null. Additionally phControlContainer.Controls.Count is zero.

Comment: This guy seems to have found a solution for controls added dynamically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17589598/4519548

Comment: He is saying that dynamic controls are always lost after postback. So he had to recreate them. Can you check if that helps you?

Comment: Yes they are lost after PostBack. So you have to keep track somewhere (ViewState, Session) which controls are added and recreate them on every page load. Or do not use `Page.IsPostBack` check when adding conrols.

Comment: Another option is to add the chart to page statically (ASPX  page using  tag <telerik:RadHtmlChart........). And control the appearance with MyChart.visible = true/false  and data using code behind events handlers.

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out. The Telerik RadHtmlChart I am using is not stored in ViewState the way I am adding it.