# Dynamically added dropdownlist losing value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdown, postback, dynamic-controls

Hi i am creating dropdownlist dynamically but on post back it is loosing the value and i am unable to get values on button click event.

```
private void CreateDropdownListEmployee(string id,Panel pnl, DataTable dt)
{
DropDownList drp = new DropDownList();
drp.ID = id;
drp.CssClass = "activeuserTxt";
drp.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
drp.DataSource = dt;
drp.DataTextField = "name";
drp.DataValueField = "id";
drp.DataBind();
pnl.Controls.Add(drp);
}
```

For the dynamic texbox i am using the below code on PAge_Init

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int SNID = 0;
            List<string> keysNetmr = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key.Contains("txt")).ToList();
            foreach (string key in keysNetmr)
            {
                this.CreateTextBox("txtNermr" + SNID, 100, pnlSN);
                SNID++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

private void CreateTextBox(string id, int width, Panel pnl)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = id;
        txt.Width = width;
        txt.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
        txt.CssClass = "activeuserTxt";
        pnl.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Created Controls losing data after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589268/dynamically-created-controls-losing-data-after-postback)

Comment: i have sorted for textboxs and labels. I am unable to resolve dropdownlist and above link is also not containing the dropdownlist example.