# How to prevent UpdatePanel from resetting values outside the panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Here is my problem :

1. I select a type using ddlType
2. I click on btnAddChoice to add a few choices
3. I click on btnSubmit to save the form

But when I try to get **ddlType.SelectedValue** in btnSubmit_Click(), it's always back to "Select a type".

If I don't do step #2 then it works fine.
From what I understand, the problem is related the ajax call (postback) and could be solved by saving the SelectedValue in the Session or ViewState.

But I have many many other controls (such as ddlType) on this page so it does not seem like an elegant solution. I was hoping for the framework to keep the selected values in the ViewState automatically ... Any idea ? After all, is it not the goal of UpdatePanel to update just the panel ?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select a type" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Three" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<div>
    <strong>Choices</strong>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddChoice" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phChoices"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ul>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddChoice" runat="server" Text="Add Choice" CausesValidation="false" 
            OnClick="btnAddChoice_Click" />
</div>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Add question" 
                           OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

**UPDATE**

Part of the problem was caused by :

```
$('#<%= MainPanel.FindControl("btnAddChoice").ClientID %>').click(function () {
    var ddlType = $('#<%= MainPanel.FindControl("ddlType").ClientID %>');
    ddlType.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456450/disabled-dropdownlist-does-not-keep-selected-value-on-postback) for details.
Regarding other controls also empty, the reason is that ["dynamically created controls have to be created each and every post-back"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881537/placeholder-controls-collection-empty-on-postback)

Comment: where is ur `ScriptManager` ?

Comment: ok I've added it to the snippet (trying to keep it short)

Comment: So basically u dont want to refresh the whole page ? is that right ?

Comment: exactly : when I click on btnAddChoice, I just want to change the UpdatePanel content and it seems to work fine ... the ddlType is not updated (visually) but in the code-behind the ddlType.SelectedValue is resetted to default value (empty)

Comment: hmm I've added the ScriptManager tag at the top of the snippet .. anything missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to your `ScriptManager`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
```

Then all the code which you want to get refreshed will come under [`Update Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

```html
<asp:Updatepanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
...All your HTML content here
</ContentTemplate>
    </asp:Updatepanel>
```

Hope that helps

More information on [`EnablePartialRendering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepartialrendering(v=vs.110).aspx)

**UPDATE**

Also if your `dropdownlist` value is not getting saved because of `Updatepanel`

try [`Request.Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx) and check

```
Request.Form.Get("dropdownlistID").ToString());
```

Comment: thanks ... I've tried it but I get the same problem (btw I think EnablePartialRendering default value is true)

Comment: can u paste your code which u tried [here](https://jsfiddle.net/) So that I can also check

Comment: your value which is selected is not getting saved right ?

Comment: exactly, ddlType.SelectedValue is resetted by btnAddChoice apparently but visually it's fine

Comment: ok I just found part of the problem, I will update my question, thanks for your help ;)

Comment: did it get resolved..Kindly let me  know what was the issue. Also if it helped please accept the answer too. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110338/discussion-between-john-marston-and-coder).